# How to reindex with MultiIndex.from_product?

Tags: python, pandas

source data :

```
data = pandas.DataFrame(
[["bainuo","pay",2418,2811,0],
["ctrip_distributor","pay",468,613,0],
["bainuo","refund",855,1001,231],
["ctrip_distributor","refund",195,264,55],
["dianpinghotel","refund",53,60,52],
["bainuo","check_in",1705,1888,184],
["ctrip_distributor","check_in",264,313,73],
["dianpinghotel","check_in",5,5,4]],columns=["partner","state","oid","quantity","roomnight"])
```

I wanna:

```
data = pandas.pivot_table(data,values=['oid','quantity','roomnight'],index=['partner'],columns=['state'])
data = data.reorder_levels([1,0],axis=1).reindex(columns=['oid','quantity','roomnight'],level=1).reindex(columns=['pay','refund','check_in'],level=0).fillna(0)
```

and it works
but when i try another way:

```
data = pandas.pivot_table(data,values=['oid','quantity','roomnight'],index=['partner'],columns=['state'])
idx = pandas.MultiIndex.from_product([['pay','refund','check_in'],['oid','quantity','roomnight']])
data = data.reindex(columns=idx)
```

the result is wrong!

Comment: They're fundamentally different approaches though, in your successful version you're creating a pivot table and reordering the levels after the pivot, in your second you're reindexing the data and the data relationships to the columns doesn't exist so you get all `NaN`s

Comment: @EdChum  sorry, there is a slip of pen,please see again,thank you

Comment: You first need to do this `.reorder_levels([1,0],axis=1)` as well in the second case, then the `reindex` with the MultiIndex will work (reindex cannot swap levels, it will try to match labels within levels, and so you get all NaNs)

Comment: @joris why not make it into an answer?

Comment: @joris oh! many thanks

Answer (score 2):

You first need to do the `.reorder_levels([1,0],axis=1)` as well in the second case, then the reindex with the MultiIndex will work:

```
data.reorder_levels([1,0],axis=1).reindex(columns=idx)
```

The reasons is that `reindex` cannot swap levels, it will only try to match labels within levels, and so you get all NaNs.